# How to decode the value of the variable that stores the value returned from glm::value_ptr()?

Tags: c++, glm-math

if I have this snippet code:

```
glm::mat4 someMatrix(1.0f);

GLfloat * a = glm::value_ptr(someMatrix);
```

How can I decode the values from the variable 'a'. I know the value is someMatrix but jus for curiosity is possible I could get the same Matrix value by decoding the variable a? I tried with this:

```
std::cout<<"value: "<< a <<"\n";   // It throws me the address : 0x7fff609e91f0
std::cout<<"value: "<< *a <<"\n"; // It gives me this value: 8.88612e-39
```

But I don't know how to get the matrix and its values. This question might be meaningless because obviously I already know the value of the matrix but just for curiosity I want to know if is possible to decode. Anyway. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*a` should really output `1` in this case though, I assume this is from another place where `a` doesn’t correspond to an identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "decoding" I'm assuming you're referring to reading each individual element of the matrix.

If it's for the purpose of printing you can do:

```
glm::mat4 someMatrix(1.0f);
std::cout << glm::to_string(someMatrix) << std::endl;
```

If you insist on using the result of `glm::value_ptr`.

```
glm::mat4 someMatrix(1.0f);
GLfloat *a = glm::value_ptr(someMatrix);

for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[j * 4 + i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which for `someMatrix` would print:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```